# How to send Magento cron job customer email

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, cron, order-email

I have been trying to no avail to have Magento send a email to a customer after they make a order. I can go into the customers order in the Sales Orders and send them a email, but the auto sender is not working. I know I have to do something with cron job to send the queue of emails, I just dont know were to start looking. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your Magento cronjob set up? http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: I was looking at it, and I had seen and I was wondering, were do I put it?                              "*/5 * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.yoursite.com/absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php"

Comment: Depends on what you're hosting Magento on. If it's Linux or Unix, the heading "UNIX/BSD/linux" gives a little information.

Comment: Ok, new question (I think) Were is the crontab file?

Comment: Which? There's a crontab for every user, as well as a systemwide /etc/crontab, and other cron files.

Comment: You could put it in /etc/crontab, but make sure to add in the user to run as (whatever user the webserver runs as, such as apache or httpd) in the line there.

Comment: Thing is, I have a search (I believe im running it through  apache) and when I search, I cant find a crontab.

Comment: Ok, the cron job was working, sent a email for the confirmation of a order, and now its not working any more...

Comment: curl -L -s http://sitename.com/cron.php I have that has my command in the cron job, and its set to 1 minute.